# EPPlus Excel Change cell color

Tags: c#, epplus

I am trying to set the color of a given cell with the color of another cell (that is already colored in the template.
But  `worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor` doesn't seem to have a `get`property.
Is it possible to do that or do I have to find the exact hexdecimal code of the color on the internet ?

**EDIT**

using the code in the answer, I get that error (it is written in French but it translate with what I wrote in my first comment)
[image]

Answer (score 6):

How about something like this?

```
//get color from this cell
var rgb = ws.Cells[1, 2].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb;
//Convert to system.drawing.color
var color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + rgb);
//set color in this cell
ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(color);
```

Update: 
Seems that if you select a color from system colors or the palette as your fill color it works fine. If you select one of the 'Theme colors' in the fill drop down `.Rgb` returns an empty string

```
//get style
var style = ws.Cells[400, 1].Style;

//If color from System colors or palette
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb))
{
   //Convert to system.drawing.colow
   var color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb);
   //set color in this cell
   ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
   ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(color);
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Theme))
{
   //No idea how to get color from Theme
}
```

I'm not sure it's supported... according to [EPPlus Faqs](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ) :

> What is NOT supported by the library (these are the most obvious features)? 
>   [...]
>   * Themes

Comment: it doesn't work, I get the error "# is not a valid value for Int32". And if I remove it, I get everything in black

Comment: on the line `var color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + rgb); `. I don't know how to add an image to the comment. I'll edit my post

Comment: That will only happen if you're getting null value back from where you are getting the color from your 'source' cell, ie `ws.Cells[1, 2].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb` . So if the background color isn't set there is will fail. Check if `ws.Cells[1, 2].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb` is null before you run the rest of the code

Comment: That is weird, considering that my source cell has a color (kind of yellow, but not really). Do you think the value is null because the source cell comes from the document template I use to open my ExcelPackage.Worksheet ?

Comment: I just noticed a weird bug there actually... if you select a standard color or a color from the palette it works fine. But if you select one of the 'Theme colors' from the fill drop down `.Rgb` returns an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone getting here, since I had my round of fun with EPPlus and I wasn't satisfied with the answers above:

```
cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.LookupColor()
```

returns #AARRGGBB color (I.E. red is #FFFF0000). The part you're interesdted in is probably the last 6 digits.

Comment: This really helped in my case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are cases where 2 different colors have the same result. no idea why.