# Epplus get correct cell background rgb color

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

i'm having trouble getting the true RGB value for Background colors with EPPLUS.

My code it's only working for colors that are setted as RGB on excel, cells with pallete colors are not getting identified.

Here's the code, hope somebody can help me out:

```css
ExcelRangeBase c = sheet.Cells[k, j];
var wbs = sheet.Workbook.Styles;
var fill = c.Style.Fill;
string rgb = "";
if (fill.PatternType == OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid)
{
  rgb = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb) ? fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb :
  fill.PatternColor.LookupColor(fill.BackgroundColor);
}
else if (fill.PatternType != OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.None)
{
  rgb = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fill.PatternColor.Rgb) ? fill.PatternColor.Rgb :
  fill.PatternColor.LookupColor(fill.PatternColor);
}
if (rgb.StartsWith("#")) rgb.Replace("#", "");
rgb = rgb.Trim();

// Removes ALPHA from ARGB
if (rgb.Length == 8 || rgb.Length == 5) rgb = rgb.Substring(2);
else if (rgb.Length > 8) rgb = rgb.Substring(rgb.Length - 6);

if (!rgb.StartsWith("#")) rgb = "#" + rgb;

string bg = "";
// I got this validation because most times lookupColor returns FF000;
if (rgb != null && rgb != "" && rgb != "#000" && rgb != "#000000")
{
  bg = "background: " + rgb + "; ";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have selected one of the 'Theme colors' in the Excel colour dropdown rather than 'Standard colors' or from the colour picker it doesn't seem to work, as described in the answer to this question here: [EPPlus Excel Change cell color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31026657/2039359)

It seems that themes are not supported - [EPPlus FAQ](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ)

> What is NOT supported by the library (these are the most obvious features)? [...] * Themes

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bunker. I understand that Themes are not supported, and I don't think I'm using them, I've used the default colors from excel. I guess they are called Tinted or Indexed in EPPlus, and I tought I could get them because of the ExcelColor.LookupColor method that says: "Return the RGB value for the color object that uses the Indexed or Tint property". I checked and there's Indexed and Tint properties on some cells that my code is return #FF000 color

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is a quirk of how `LookupColor` works in EPPlus. Specifically, the format of color [returned in this case is AA{R}{G}{B}](https://github.com/drola/EPPlus/blob/master/Style/ExcelColor.cs), with two characters for alpha and a constant length sequence for each of R, G, and B respectively, specifying a shade of grey. HOWEVER, if you look at the code, you could get some really quite weird colors out (i.e. it's probably bugged). That's because the constant length used can range from 1 to 3 characters with a ceiling of `0x0200`.

For instance, `((int)(decimal.Round(-1M * -512))).ToString("X")` returns `"200"`, which by inference, would result in a return of `#FF200200200`. However, short of submitting a patch to change how this is handled, probably the way to do this is to trust that that *is* the ceiling that can be returned for a channel, and then scale between 0->FF.

For an approach to doing this, see below. Please note that if this *is* ever fixed in EPPlus itself, the below will scale things incorrectly (since the actual ceiling will be `FF`, not `0x0200`).

```
private string EPPLookupColorFixed(ExcelColor sourceColor)
    {
        var lookupColor = sourceColor.LookupColor();
        const int maxLookup = 63;
        bool isFromTable = (0 <= sourceColor.Indexed) && (maxLookup > sourceColor.Indexed);
        bool isFromRGB = (null != sourceColor.Rgb && 0 < sourceColor.Rgb.Length);
        if (isFromTable || isFromRGB)
            return lookupColor;

        // Ok, we know we entered the else block in EPP - the one 
        // that doesn't quite behave as expected.

        string shortString = "0000";
        switch (lookupColor.Length)
        {
            case 6:
                // Of the form #FF000
                shortString = lookupColor.Substring(3, 1).PadLeft(4, '0');
                break;
            case 9:
                // Of the form #FFAAAAAA
                shortString = lookupColor.Substring(3, 2).PadLeft(4, '0');
                break;
            case 12:
                // Of the form #FF200200200
                shortString = lookupColor.Substring(3, 3).PadLeft(4, '0');
                break;
        }
        var actualValue = short.Parse(shortString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        var percent = ((double)actualValue) / 0x200d;
        var byteValue = (byte)Math.Round(percent * 0xFF,0);
        var byteText = byteValue.ToString("X");
        byteText = byteText.Length == 2 ? byteText : byteText.PadLeft(2, '0');
        return $"{lookupColor.Substring(0, 3)}{byteText}{byteText}{byteText}";
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, but LookupColor doesn't help for any of the theme colors - EPPlus does not support themes and you cannot discern which color the tint corresponds to without knowing the theme applied to the sheet the range you're looking at belongs to.