# Epplus TabColor only returns black - RGB (0, 0, 0)

Tags: c#, epplus

My code is below:

`MainTabColor = ws.TabColor;`

Everything else works fine, but TabColor always returns black, though the color of the tab on the spreadsheet is orange.

Going through the RGB values, they are all zero.

I'm wondering if the {get, set} of TabColor only has the "set", and the "get" doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that Epplus does not support "theme" colors.
So if the color of a tab, or even the cell style background color, is selected from the actual color palette, if will work.

Selecting a color from the pre-set color scheme / theme will give a blank result (black).

[More information in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35941241/)